# Add attribute to the child without generating new XML element

Tags: xml, go

How can I create this XML using the Go XML package?

```
<Files><File width="200" height="100">somevaluehere</File></Files>
```

It is harder than you may think, for example:

```
type Video struct {
    Files Files `xml:"Files"`
}

type Files struct {
    Width  string `xml:"Width,attr"`
    Height string `xml:"Height,attr"`
    File   string `xml:"File"`
}
```

the output is:

```
<Video><Files Width="640" Height="480"><File>somevalue</File></Files></Video>
```

And I want:

```
<Video><Files><File Width="640" Height="480">somevalue</File></Files></Video>
```

Comment: Model your data with a struct, and use `encoding/xml` to generate the XML output.

Comment: @icza  I added some examples! if you have the answer,  please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `Video.Files` to be rendered into `<Video><Files><File>` tag, so indicate this in the tag:

```
type Video struct {
    Files Files `xml:"Files>File"`
}
```

And you want the `Files.File` value to be the tag's char data, also indicate this in the tag:

```
type Files struct {
    Width  string `xml:"Width,attr"`
    Height string `xml:"Height,attr"`
    File   string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

Testing it:

```
v := Video{
    Files: Files{
        Width:  "640",
        Height: "480",
        File:   "someValue",
    },
}
out, err := xml.Marshal(v)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JsilGQxpaZ8)):

```
<Video><Files><File Width="640" Height="480">someValue</File></Files></Video>
```

If there could me multiple `<File>` elements inside `<Files>`, I would make `Video.Files` a slice:

```
type Video struct {
    Files []File `xml:"Files>File"`
}

type File struct {
    Width  string `xml:"Width,attr"`
    Height string `xml:"Height,attr"`
    File   string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

Testing it:

```
v := Video{
    Files: []File{
        {
            Width:  "640",
            Height: "480",
            File:   "someValue",
        },
        {
            Width:  "320",
            Height: "240",
            File:   "otherValue",
        },
    },
}
out, err := xml.Marshal(v)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XIoNHscX8s-)):

```
<Video><Files><File Width="640" Height="480">someValue</File><File Width="320" Height="240">otherValue</File></Files></Video>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you.